# Convert Javascript 'new object' to literal notation

Tags: javascript, oop, object, aptana, object-literal

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 to code Javascript OOP, i'm creating class and objects using the 'new' and 'this', but is really annoying because none IDE autocomplete doesn't recognize my objects properties and methods.

maybe if i change to literal notation, the IDE recognize my objects and enable the Auto Complete function, but I can't translate my code to a literal notation keeping the same functionalities.

I wrote a sample, how I usually write.

```
var ClassPerson=function(name,lastName){

    //initialize stuff here
    alert(name + ' was just created now!');

    var time=setInterval( function(){getOlder(1);} ,(1000*60*60*24*365));

    //public properties
    this.name=name;
    this.lastName=lastName;

    //private properties
    var age=0;
    var weight=3;

    var parent=this; //reference to 'this' of this object, not the caller object.

    //public methods
    this.speak=function(text){  
        alert(text);
    }

    this.walk=function(steps){
        weight=weight-(0.05*steps);
    }

    this.eat=function(kcal){
        weight=weight+(kcal/2);
    }

    //private methods
    function getOlder(years){
        age=age+years;
    }
}

var me = new ClassPerson('Justin','Victor');
me.speak( me.name );
me.eat(2500);
```

If someone can convert this to literal, maybe I can figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example:

```
var sample = function (a,b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
} 
var sampleObj = new sample(0,1);
sampleObj.a == 0; // true    

var a = 0, b = 1;
var sample = {
    a: a,
    b: b
}
sample.a == 0; // true
```

Comment: var obj={ method1:function(params){return(params);}, method2:function(params){return(params);} } still correct? how about private and public scope? Thanks

Comment: You don't get private scope with object notation, one draw back for sure

Answer (score 0):

// Would it help to call var johnsmith=ClassPerson('John','Smith'), without using the new keyword?

```
function ClassPerson(name, lastName){
    if(!(this instanceOf ClassPerson)) return new Classperson(name, lastName);
    //constructor code
```